# laravel app won't appear on localhost

Tags: laravel, localhost

I am having issues with my xampp and locahost and laravel projects. When I create a new laravel project: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel fmvcei in my C:/xampp/htdocs folder, when I type in localhost/fmvcei/public, nothing appears. I pulled from another stack overflow question on this where it suggested removing the NameVirtualHost *:80. When I try to configure my host files to be able to type fmvcei.test in the browser, still nothing. I have restarted xampp each time. Here are my httpd/vhost and host files:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName localhost

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride all
       Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/fmvcei/public"
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName fmvcei.test
    ServerAlias www.fmvcei.test

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/fmvcei/public">
       AllowOverride All
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

       Require local
       # if you want access from other pc's on your local network
       #Require ip 192.168.1
       # Only if you want the world to see your site
       #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   tbhtoat.app
127.0.0.1   fmvcei.test
```

Comment: From my experience I would suggest using https://laragon.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things, make sure both Apache and MySQL are running.

Move to the root project directory, **fmvcei** in your case, then run this command `php artisan serve`. you can browse by **127.0.0.1:8000**

**NB.** you need to install composer if you don't yet.

Comment: I mistakenly ran a php artisan serve as well as trying to configure through xampp, so i deleted the new project and reinstalled it with the necessary changes to my apache/extra and windows/system32/driver files and was able to run it as so: http://fmvcon.test:3200/